# How to apply different rate limits for different paths in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to apply a global throttle to all my API requests but for some paths apply a special rule. I could remove throttle middleware from Kernel.php and split all routes in groups but this would create a mess in routes file. Is there a way to keep a throttle middleware in Kernel.php applied to all routes and override its behavior for certain routes like this

```
Route::get(...)->middleware('throttle:10,1');
```

OR

```
Route::get(...)->middleware('throttle-override:10,1');
```

Note: I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698098/laravel-different-api-rate-limits-for-different-paths) question and it is different from mine.

Comment: All I can think of, is to create middleware yourself, within it, use the $request to obtain the path, depending on the path apply throttle with different parameters, and a default. Don't forget to remove the throttle from the kernel.php and add your own middleware instead.

Comment: Is there a way to see the list of all middleware objects attached to route from within middleware? If yes I could modify existing throttle middleware to ignore the request if there is another throttle attached further down the line.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. I however have no experience with doing that :). I suggest you take a closer look at `Closure $next` (the 2nd parameter of the `handle` method in the middleware). Make sure to place your middleware above the throttle middleware, else it wont work (obviously)